# Proof, Factor theorem.

Tags: solution-verification, factoring

Question is :

**If $f(x)$ is a polynomial with integral coefficients and, suppose that $f(1)$ and
$f(2)$ both are odd, then prove that there exists no integer n for which $f(n) = 0.$**

My approach :

I tried writing the function in form of quotient, remainder and divisor.
(I have assumed the remainder to be linear.)

$f(x) = Q(x)D(x) + ax + b$

$f(x) = K(x-1)(x-2) + ax + b  \longrightarrow (1)$

$f(x) = K_1(x-1) + (2n_1 +1)  \longrightarrow (2)$

$f(x) = K_2(x-1) + (2n_2 +1)  \longrightarrow (3)$

I tried the above, but it isn't proving to be of much help.

On the other hand, if I think reverse, the possible way I can think of when a polynomial with integral coefficients has no integer n for which $f(n)=0$  is probably when it has odd coefficients, because in that case, the roots aren't rational. I don't know how to relate this with the question, however.

Please help me with a quick method for this problem. Kindly verify if I have done any mistakes. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose, there is an integer $\ n\ $ with $\ f(n)=0\ $

Then, $\ x-n\ $ is a factor of $\ f(x)\ $ which is even for either $\ x=1\ $ or $\ x=2\ $ , hence at least one of $\ f(1)\ $ and $\ f(2)\ $ must be even.

Comment: This might be silly, but I did not understand how you said " $x−n$   is a factor of $ f(x)$  which is  **even** for either $ x=1$  or  $  x=2 $ ". I understood the factor part of it but I didn't understand why it should be necessarily even.

Comment: For a fixed $n$, if $1-n$ is odd then $2-n$ is even and vice versa. So exactly one is even.

Comment: Oh right. Thanks a lot!